# Laravel 4 - Find out what route was hit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Well I have a little problem, and I don't know if I'm blind to find it inside the Laravel 4 Documentation or it doesn't even exist ...

I have two routes that route to one and the same controller function...

```
//List blog_posts
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@listPosts');
//List deleted blog_posts
Route::get('/bin', 'BlogController@listPosts');
```

Now, is there a way to determine inside the 'listPosts' function what route was hit ?

Of course I could create another function inside 'BlogController' but I dont like that idea ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `Route::current()`.  It will return an object of type `Illuminate\Routing\Route` which has a method on it called `getUri`:

```
var_dump(Route::current()->getUri());
```

If you [gave your routes a name](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#named-routes), you can also make a decision based off of that:

```
var_dump(Route::currentRouteName());
```

Comment: Damn, you edited the named route in part as I wrote a post on it. :-p

Answer (score 1):

You can also use named routes:

```
Route::get('/', ['as' => 'listIndex', 'uses' => 'BlogController@listPosts']);
Route::get('/bin', ['as' => 'listBin', 'uses' => 'BlogController@listPosts']);
```

This will set `Route::currentRouteName()` which you could if/else on.